# Unable to have uikit modal show when included in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, uikit

I would like to have a modal window using uikit popup in my react application.

When I include this code in my public/index.html file the modal is showing correctly:

```
<a uk-toggle href="#my-id">Teste Modal bg-close:false</a>
<div id="my-id" uk-modal="bg-close: false">
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
    <button class="uk-modal-close-default" type="button" uk-close></button>
    <p>This modal can NOT be close by just clicking outside of it ...</p>
    <p>Please click on the X at the top right to close it.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it will not work if I try to use it from inside a react component like this:

```
<a className="uk-toggle" href="#my-id">Test Modal bg-close:false</a>
<div id="my-id" uk-modal="bg-close: false">
  <div className="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
    <button className="uk-modal-close-default" type="button" uk-close></button>
    <p>This modal can NOT be close by just clicking outside of it ...</p>
    <p>Please click on the X at the top right to close it.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can see the link but the click doesn't have any effect.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

I added a jsfiddle, and I confirm the react version is still not working...
https://jsfiddle.net/umfk8jnc/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `data-` prefix. Here is an updated JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pd8nt5mx/

> NOTE React will work with data-uk-* prefixes only.

Source: https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript#component-usage